# PHP loop to get todays date and the following 9 days

Tags: php, date

I have the following php code:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$index = 0;


while( $index <10){
    $date->modify('+'. $index .' day');
    print $date->format('Y-m-d') . ' - index: ' . $index . '<br/>';
    $index++; 
}
```

**What this script should do:** it should display todays date and the next 9 dates for the following days: ( I also printed the $index value each time to make sure the index it's right all time).

**What it actually displays:**

```
2017-05-29 - index: 0
2017-05-30 - index: 1
2017-06-01 - index: 2
2017-06-04 - index: 3
2017-06-08 - index: 4
2017-06-13 - index: 5
2017-06-19 - index: 6
2017-06-26 - index: 7
2017-07-04 - index: 8
2017-07-13 - index: 9
```

**NOTE:** See how from date **2017-06-01** jumps to **2017-06-04** and then to **2017-06-08** and so on.

I have no idea why this happens, can someone tell me? Is this even the right approach ?

Comment: It is normal that it will print 2017-06-01 and the next one is 2017-06-04 cause the index is changing from 1 to 3 ! it like adding 3 days instead of just one !

Answer (score 4):

As you want to add 1 day on every iteration, you don't need to use the index on the sum, just use `$date->modify("+1 day");`.

Also, put the line where you print the date before you modify it.

What happens in your code is that you start adding 0 on the first iteration, which then you print the actual day. Next iteration, you add 1, so tomorrow is printed. Next iteration, you add 2, and skip 1 day. Next, add 3, and skip 2 days... And this over and over.

Comment: Yes you are right, this is a piece of code simplified and cut of a much more complex script and the index has supposed to be used elsewhere and I accidently used it here, beginner mistake :)) thank you

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the value of `$index` let it equal = 1 , or even try to do "+1 day" in the `modify()` function

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
echo date("y-m-d",strtotime($i." day"))."<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this loop

```
$begin = new DateTime("2017-05-29");
$end = new DateTime("2017-06-8");
$end = $end->modify('+1 day');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');

$index = 0;
foreach ($period as $dt) {
    if ($index == 9) {
        break;
    }

    echo $dt->format("Y-m-d");
    $index = $index + 1;
}
```